# Trabalhar com dois forms diferentes no mesmo local

Tags: php, html

Estou fazendo alguns algoritmos básicos com php, e então de curiosidade decidi fazer um html com um `form`, `input text` e um botão para enviar. no PHP.
Se a variável que coloquei no `input text` for igual a 1, o php exibe outro form abaixo. 
Tentei digitar algo nesse input text e enviar, mas não aconteceu nada, mesmo eu tendo criado um algorítmo que iria exibir o número na tela.

Segue o código:

```
<html>

<head><font face="Arial">
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
Valor:<input type="text" name="n1"><br>
<input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar"></form>
<input type="hidden" name="n2" value="0">
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['n1']) || isset($n1))
{
    if(isset($_POST["valor1"]))
    {
        $n1=$_POST['valor1'];
    }   
    else
    {
        $n1 = $_POST['n1']; 
    }
    if(isset($_POST["valor2"]))
    {
        $n2=$_POST['valor2'];
    }   
    else
    {
        $n2 = $_POST['n2']; 
    }
    if($n1 == 1)
    {
    echo '<form method="POST">Valor:<input type="text" name="n2"><br>
<input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar"></form>
<input type="hidden" name="valor1" value="'.$n1.'">
<input type="hidden" name="valo2" value="'.$n2.'">';
}
if(isset($_POST['n2']) || isset($n2))
{
    echo $n2;
}

}
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Não consigo identificar a variavel do`textarea`, nem mesmo encontrei um [textarea](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp), explica um pouco mais sobre sua dúvida e verifica se esta tudo no exemplo

Comment: Perdão, confundi `text area` com `input text`. E eu gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de criar um `form` à partir do php que funcione

Comment: que consiga ser lido pelo algorítmo e que exiba seu valor na tela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Montei a partir do seu código um exemplo, existem formas mais diretas e menos verbosa de fazer a mesma coisa, porém, procurei deixar mais legível.

```
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>

    <?php
    $n1 = "";
    if(isset($_POST['n1']))
    {
        $n1 = $_POST['n1'];
    }
    $n2 = "";
    if(isset($_POST['n2']))
    {
        $n2 = $_POST['n2'];
    }

    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        Valor1:<input type="text" name="n1" value="<?php echo $n1; ?>"><br>

        <?php

        if($n1 != "")
        {
            echo 'Valor2:<input type="text" name="n2" value="' . $n2 . '"><br>';
        }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar">
    </form>
    <hr>
    Valor 1 = <?php echo $n1; ?><br>
    Valor 2 = <?php echo $n2; ?><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tive que corrigir algumas partes do código pois onde estou testando ele não consegue ler alguns comandos. Mas funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado